# Why I cannot use previous argument values to define argument default values?

Tags: c++, default-arguments

For example, why I cannot write this:

```
void f(double x, double y = x);
```

to declare a function `f`, for which the call `f(x)` is equivalent to `f(x,x)`?

In case this doesn't seem useful to you, here's a possible usage scenario. In this example, I declare `f` as follows:

```
void f(double x, double y = expensiveComputation(x));
```

where `expensiveComputation` denotes, you guessed it, a function that does a very slow computation. I want to give the user of `f` the possibility of passing in the value of `y` if he has computed it previously, so I don't have to compute it again inside `f`. Now, of course I can also resolve this by writing two overloads:

```
void f(double x, double y);
void f(double x) { f(x, expensiveComputation(x)); }
```

but writing overloads becomes tiresome as the number of arguments grows. For example, try to write:

```
void f(double x, double p = expensiveComputation(x), 
                 double q = expensiveComputation2(x, p), 
                 double r = expensiveComputation3(x, p, q),
                 double s = expensiveComputation3(x, p, q, r));
```

using overloads. It's just uglier. Default arguments are sexy. Is there a deeper syntactic reason why previous arguments can't be used to define argument default values?

Comment: Allowing this syntax would force the implementation to evaluate arguments from left to right?

Comment: @Brian Good point. Why is it that the implementation isn't forced to evaluate arguments left to right? I forgot...

Comment: On many platforms the default calling convention is to push arguments onto the stack starting from the rightmost and proceeding left. (The callee then pops from left to right.)

Comment: @Brian But there's no necessary link between the order of evaluation and the order in which the results are pushed ?

Comment: @Quentin The calling code gets more complicated if arguments are evaluated and pushed in different orders.

Comment: @Brian oh, because the result is still in the registers. Makes sense.

Comment: Only tangentially related, but fwiw if you really had that many overloads in a single, complicated function like that, I would consider making it a function object which essentially holds the computed intermediate values, and make f a method of it, and use delegating constructors to simplify the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why default argument can't go that way, but maybe you can try to wrap all those arguments in a struct(class)?

```
struct ParamSet
{
    double x;
    double p;
    double q;

    ParamSet(double x)
        : x(x)
        , p(ExpensiveCompute1(x))
        , q(ExpensiveCompute2(x, p))
    {
    }
    ParamSet(double x, double p)
        : x(x)
        , p(p)
        , q(ExpensiveCompute2(x, p))
    {
    }
    ParamSet(double x, double p, double q)
        : x(x), p(p), q(q)
    {
    }

private:
    double ExpensiveCompute1(double x) {}
    double ExpensiveCompute2(double x, double p) {}
};      
void f(ParamSet ps);
```

Still need ctor overloads, but no more works than writing the `expensiveComputation()` series like you provided, and at least all things are wrapped in the struct

Also, signature of `f()` could be fixed, and there is only 1 version.

Answer (score 0):

You may use variadic templates for something similar:

```
template<typename... Args> void f(double x, Args... args)
{
    typedef typename common_type<double, Args...>::type common;
    std::vector<common, sizeof...(args)> arguments = {{ args... }};

    if (arguments.size < 2) arguments.push_back(expensiveComputation(arguments[0]));
    if (arguments.size < 3) arguments.push_back(expensiveComputation2(arguments[0], arguments[1]));
    if (arguments.size < 4) arguments.push_back(expensiveComputation3(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]));
    if (arguments.size < 5) arguments.push_back(expensiveComputation4(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3]));
}
```